# How to login to application after assigning user using custom authentication in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm new in oracle apex and i'm trying to make a custom authorization for the user login to the application. I have make a custom authentication for the login using this PL/SQL Code (it's already work)

```
FUNCTION user_aut    (
 p_username IN VARCHAR2, --User_Name
 p_password IN VARCHAR2 -- Password    
)
 RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
lc_pwd_exit VARCHAR2 (60);
BEGIN
 -- Validate whether the user exits or not
 SELECT 'Active'
 INTO lc_pwd_exit
 FROM USER_PROFILE
 WHERE upper("user_name") = UPPER (p_username) AND password = p_password and status='Active'
;
RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 THEN
 RETURN FALSE;
END user_aut;
```

but when i want to login using this i need to assign the user in "Application Access Control". How to make the user can login without manually assign the user to application access control? or how to make custom authorization for the user to login to the application? Any suggestion Please help. Thank You

[Error when did not add the user to application access control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ieY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing 2 concepts: [Authorization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmdb/providing-security-through-authorization.html#GUID-8FBF5F46-0541-4859-8470-D10E333DD271) and [Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmdb/understanding-authentication.html#GUID-144A774D-2B05-4BE5-9550-6951EE0B536B). You created an **authentication** scheme - that is needed to grant the user access to the application. Once he is in the application, **authorization** schemes determine what privileges a user has in the application.

The error message indicates that there is an authorization scheme called "Reader Rights" set on the page/component that is being rendered and the uses does not have access to it.

It's up to you how you want to continue:

- Do you want to use the authorization schemes created by the application wizard (reader/contributor/administrator)
- or do you want to use and maintain your own

If you want to use the ones created by the application wizard, then there is a setting under "Administration" to allow any authenticated user to access the application - in the application itself not the builder. The path is Administration > Access Control > Access Control > "Any authenticated user may access this application"